# Adding coefficient group titles to modelsummary output

Tags: r, modelsummary

I'm trying to group coefficients together in a modelsummary output table and add row titles for these groups :

```
library(modelsummary)

ols1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp,
  data = mtcars,
  na.action = na.omit
)

modelsummary(ols1,
  title = "Table 1",
  stars = TRUE
)
```

The modelsummary documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modelsummary/modelsummary.pdf) suggests this might be something to do with the *shape* and *group_map* arguments, but I can't really figure out how to use them.

Any guidance would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: In the example you provided, what defines "groups"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the documentation mentions “groups”, it refers to models like multinomial logits where each predictor has one coefficient per outcome level. In this example, the “group” column is called “response”:

```r
library(nnet)
library(modelsummary)

mod <- multinom(cyl ~ mpg + hp, data = mtcars, trace = FALSE)

modelsummary(
    mod,
    output = "markdown",
    shape = response ~ model)
```

|  |  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 6 | 0.500 |
|  |  | (41.760) |
|  | 8 | 8.400 |
|  |  | (0.502) |
| mpg | 6 | -83.069 |
|  |  | (416.777) |
|  | 8 | -120.167 |
|  |  | (508.775) |
| hp | 6 | 16.230 |
|  |  | (81.808) |
|  | 8 | 20.307 |
|  |  | (87.777) |
| Num.Obs. |  | 32 |
| R2 |  | 1.000 |
| R2 Adj. |  | 0.971 |
| AIC |  | 12.0 |
| BIC |  | 20.8 |
| RMSE |  | 0.00 |

What you probably mean is something different: Adding manual labels to sets of coefficients. This is easy to achieve because `modelsummary()` produces a `kableExtra` or a `gt` table which can be customized in infinite ways.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

For example, you may want to look at the `group_rows` function from `kableExtra`:

```r
library(kableExtra)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars)
modelsummary(mod) |>
    group_rows(index = c("Uninteresting" = 4,
                         "Interesting" = 4,
                         "Other" = 7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. In case anyone is interested, it seems you can do a similar thing with pack_rows [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html)